# Win32: Impossible to use iocp with stdin handle

Tags: c, asynchronous, winapi, stdin, iocp

I want to make asynchronous read on stdin in Windows with I/O Completion Ports but this code doesn't works :

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Kernel32.lib")

int main() {
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD number;

    HANDLE iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(handle, NULL, 0, 0);

    if(iocp == NULL) {
        printf("error : %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

I get the error 87 : ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Comment: IOCP requires file handles that were opened with async. I don't believe it's possible to open stdin/stdout with async.

Comment: I don't find anything to open stdin with async...

Comment: if you target only latest windows version (8+) you need `CreateFile(L"CONIN$", FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);` instead `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);` after this you can use `CreateIoCompletionPort` but much better and simply use `BindIoCompletionCallback` here. another question which general logic sckeleton you want get here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateIOCompletionPort cannot be used directly with stdin/stdout.
Check [this](https://tim.mcnamara.nz/post/176613307022/iocp-and-stdio). Either use a thread, or redirect stdin/stdout to named pipes.

Comment: Thank you ! I think I will create a thread...the Windows API is very strange in comparaison to the UNIX API

Comment: Forget everything that comes from unix when programming windows and also use std::thread for simple threads.

Comment: really can be used. we can open console in asynchronous mode `CreateFile(L"CONIN$", FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);` and then bind it to iocp or better via `BindIoCompletionCallback`. but this will be work from win7 or win8 (forgot already) when console model changed and not console handles really file handle